# MVC DataValidationAttribute not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, attributes

Like most out-of-the-box .Net MVC validation attributes, I'm expecting the custom validation below to alert the user to an error before they submit the page. For example, if I set up a field to be a max length of 9 characters and they input 12, a message will appear correcting the user once they go over the limit.

I've created a custom validation attribute to compare a start and end date range, and I'd like it to behave the same way (alert the user before submitting the form). However, the only error message that I can get to display is the standard "This is not a proper date format" message.  I cannot get my custom error messages to display and, after setting a breakpoint on the `IsValid` method, it looks like this code isn't even being run.

**Custom Validation Attribute**

```
public class DateValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private DateTime? _rangeStart;
    private DateTime? _rangeEnd;
    private string _defaultErrorMessage;
    private string _propertyNameToCompare;
    private ValidationType _validationType;

    public enum ValidationType
    {
        StartCompareToEnd,
        EndCompareToStart
    }

    public DateValidationAttribute(ValidationType type, string message, string compareWith ="")
    {
        _validationType = type;
        _propertyNameToCompare = compareWith;
        _defaultErrorMessage = message;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var basePropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_propertyNameToCompare);
        Type classType = typeof(PENSGC_Generator.Models.FormViewModel);
        PropertyInfo methodInfo = classType.GetProperty(_propertyNameToCompare);
        DisplayAttribute displayAttribute =
            (DisplayAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(methodInfo, typeof(DisplayAttribute));

        switch (_validationType)
        {
            case ValidationType.EndCompareToStart:
                _rangeEnd = (DateTime)basePropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                _rangeStart = (DateTime) value;
                break;
            case ValidationType.StartCompareToEnd:
                _rangeStart = (DateTime)basePropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                _rangeEnd = (DateTime) value;
                break;
        }

        string message = string.Format(_defaultErrorMessage, validationContext.DisplayName, displayAttribute.Name);

        if (!_rangeStart.HasValue)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(message);
        }
        else if (_rangeEnd.HasValue)
        {
            if (_rangeStart >= _rangeEnd)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(message);
            }
        }

        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

**Model Properties**

```
    [DisplayName("Range Start")]
    [DateValidation(DateValidationAttribute.ValidationType.StartCompareToEnd,  "Start Date must be less than End Date", compareWith: "SearchCreatedRangeEnd")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> SearchCreatedRangeStart { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Range End")]
    [DateValidation(DateValidationAttribute.ValidationType.EndCompareToStart,  "End Date must be greater than Start Date", compareWith: "SearchCreatedRangeStart")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> SearchCreatedRangeEnd { get; set; }
```

**View/Razor**

```
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SearchCreatedRangeStart)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchCreatedRangeStart, new { style = "width:80px;" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchCreatedRangeStart)
                </div>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SearchCreatedRangeEnd)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchCreatedRangeEnd, new { style = "width:80px;" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchCreatedRangeEnd)
                </div>
            </td> 
        </tr>
```

Any ideas? First time using custom attributes, would love any words of wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest using EditorFor instead of TextBoxFor when dealing with DateTime inputs.

In order to custom validation to work on client, the custom validation validation attribute **must implement IClientValidatable** interface and then you must **write a custom javascript validation method for that attribute** in order for JQuery validate understand it.

Here's an article on how to implement similar validation on client and server side with attributes:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/780992/Asp-Net-MVC-Custom-Compare-Data-annotation-with-Cl